# If loop continue is executing for loop again

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

```
if eqp_id:
    for rule in items:
        if rule.eqp_pricelist == True:
            print "id 1"
            print rule.id
            continue
        print "id 2 out"
        print rule.id

#outputs:
#id1
#5
#id 2 out
#4
```

How is it possible that `rule.id = 5` comes before `rule.id = 4`

This code is for product_pricelist for method :

```
def _price_rule_get_multi(self, cr, uid, pricelist, products_by_qty_by_partner, context=None):
```

Comment: it can be that the entries in the `items` container are not sequential. What type of container is `items`?

Comment: `items = self.pool.get('product.pricelist.item').browse(cr, uid, item_ids, context=context)` thier id is serial i checked in database .. is there any other better way of traversing ?

Comment: what do you mean you checked  in database? iterating through `dictionary keys` for example follows a random order regardless of the order in which the entries seem to be. Are you using libraries or sets?

Comment: extremely sorry  this is items:`(5, 4 , 3)` ... its tuple

Comment: `tuples` preserve order but to get what you want you have to sort it first by `items = sorted(items)`

Comment: that wont work as the output is `product.pricelist.item(5,4,3)`..all sorted does is `[product.pricelist.item(5,),product.pricelist.item(4,),product.pricelist.item(3,)]` as i am using the odoo framework and this data is getting pulled from the database.

Comment: is it so important to you to have them sequential? You can still sort them the way you want by builting a `key` like: `a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: product.pricelist.item(x,))`

Comment: i dont need them sequential i just want what gets selected in the if loop also out of the if loop .....i want id:5 and after the if loop continues the id changes to id:4

Comment: You have to do some reading my friend @maharshi... `continue` returns execution to the nearest nesting `for` or `while` loop, so when the `print "id 2 out"` is reached it is with a different `rule`

Comment: But when i use `break` it gives me the same result. My understand of break is that the break statement in Python terminates the current loop and resumes execution at the next statement.

Comment: what should be your expected output if you have `(5,2,3,2,1)`

Comment: The expected output depends on the inner if condition i.e `if rule.eqp_pricelist == True:` Whatever gets selected in that condition is the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in your comment, if `items` is acquired using: `items = self.pool.get('product.pricelist.item').browse(cr, uid, item_ids, context=context)` then `items` is a "recordset" of Odoo ORM, so you can use a **`sorted()`** function of Odoo ORM ([see documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.sorted)):

> `sorted(key=None, reverse=False)` Return the recordset `self` ordered by
>   `key`.
>
> **Parameters**:
>      **key** -- either a function of one argument that returns a comparison key for each record, or None, in which case records are ordered according the default model's order
>      **reverse** -- if True, return the result in reverse order

In order to apply this function to your code change it as follows:

```
if eqp_id:
    for rule in items.sorted(key=lambda r: r.id):  ## sort by id using sort()...
        if rule.eqp_pricelist == True:
            print "id 1"
            print rule.id
            continue
        print "id 2 out"
        print rule.id
```

EDIT:
I do not see clearly your goal, but check also `filtered()` if it can help you:

```
if eqp_id:
    for rule in items.sorted(key=lambda r: r.id).filtered(lambda r: r.eqp_pricelist == True):  ## sort by id using sort() AND filtered using eqp_pricelist == True...
        print "[True?] Rule with eqp_pricelist == %s" % rule.eqp_pricelist
        print rule.id
```

OR:

```
if eqp_id:
    for rule in items.sorted(key=lambda r: r.id).filtered(lambda r: r.eqp_pricelist == Talse):  ## sort by id using sort() AND filtered using eqp_pricelist == False...
        print "[False?] Rule with eqp_pricelist == %s" % rule.eqp_pricelist
        print rule.id
```

you can apply just `filtered()` without `sorted()` as well.

Check out this: `for rule in items.filtered("eqp_pricelist"):`

Comment: A side note: `items = self.pool.get('product.pricelist.item').browse(cr, uid, item_ids, context=context)` is a kind of deprecated old style code since v8.0,  consider to use `items = self.env['product.pricelist.item'].browse(item_ids)` instead.